# Replace BackgroundWorker polling database with Async/Await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, polling

I have a C# class that uses a BackgroundWorker to poll a specific database table for changes. If something changes, it fires an event. Additionally, I have a class Token that has a handler for this event which basically sets the tokens state to "dirty".

Now I asked myself if there can be something better than polling the database every few miliseconds. I thought of making an asynchronous method in my token like

```
public async Task<bool> IsDirty()
{
    return await Something();
}
```

But what should I await here? My BackgroundWorker only has its Do_Work and RunWorkerCompleted methods. The BackgroundWorker doesn't need to check all the time, but at least when someone calls/awaits the IsDirty() method.

Comment: Consider replacing BackgroundWorker with Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is something definitely better than polling the DB. [Using SqlDependency in a Windows Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You can create a dependency object where SQL Server will notify you that something has changed (a record inserted, updated, deleted).

Comment: I know about SqlDependency, but it makes my application really slow since it blocks when executing the query and I don't have the possibilty to make the execution-call asynchronous. When checking bigger queries (e.g. 2 or more joins), it takes up to 2 seconds. This is why I built this wrapper around the change tracking feature of SQL Server for polling the CHANGETABLE() function.